# Manipulating Audio of a live Video Streaming

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, audio-streaming

We have a streaming video URL.

We have different music genres in our Application like Acoustic,Rock,Classical etc..

Our requirement is whenever we choose any of the music genre mentioned above, audio of stream should change accordingly.

Can anyone please suggest us,is there any way in iOS or Android by which we can extract Audio Stream from the live streaming and can manipulate AudioData according to selected genre.

Thanks

Comment: It would be much easier to simply mute the video audio and play another stream along side it.

Comment: @Brad Thanx for your help. :)
Actually it is not our requirement.We need to extract audio from live video stream and then want to change audio genre like Acoustic,Classical etc.
I just need to reassure whether we can change the audio data at a run time or not?

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is between what you're asking for and what I suggested.  Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Brad  We have our custom media player.
 We have to play  videos  from Youtube in media player .
 Media Player has some options to change the music genre like Acoustic,Classical,Rock etc.
 So is it possible to change the audio according to selected music genre at a run time.

Comment: Why not mute the YouTube audio and play music at the same time?

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your prompt reply..:)
Lets make it simple.Actually Streaming data from Youtube contains both Video and Audio.So is it possible to filter and modify audio from the whole streaming.